# Error in SSAS Tabular: An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas-tabular

I have a SSAS tabular. I'm trying to create a expression.

The code is the next:

```
= Sql.Database("ServerName", "mydatabase",[Query="SELECT * FROM DW_D_AC_CERTIF_OPER_DIM"])
```

But when I try to process the partition it gives me the following error:

> An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In Tabular, you create data sources first. Then you reference them by name in M in place of `"ServerName"` in your code.

[image: DataSources referenced in M]

Comment: I would be very helpfull if you could give a little less blur in the m query. If I reference the predefined source... how can I subsequently specifiy the SQL query?

Comment: You can use your code. Add the Data Source, let's say as SQLServerName. Wrap the name like this: #"name_goes_here", then just insert it in your code: =Sql.Database(#"SQLServerName", "mydatabase", [Query="SELECT * FROM DW_D_AC_CERTIF_OPER_DIM"]).

Comment: I have a Data Source named `SRVAPP01` and now get `Expression in partition x in table y references an unknown entity`, so that looks like a small step forward but I'm clearly still missing something. My partition is defined as (simplified):
`let
    #"Source" = #"SRVAPP01",
    Query = Sql.Database(#"Source", "MyDatabaseName", [Query="SELECT * FROM myTable", CreateNavigationProperties=false, CommandTimeout=#duration(0, 0, 10, 0)])
in
    Query`

Comment: Ah, found it:
`let
    Source = #"SRVAPP01",
    Query = Value.NativeQuery(
        Source, "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
    )
in Query`